# Got an error while submitting an extension in magento connect

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-connect, magento-connect-manager

I am facing one issue while uploading a magento extension/plugin on magento connect.

I have generated my custom plugin successfully from magento admin feature

> SYSTEM --> Magento Connect --> Package Extensions

But when I am trying to upload this extension in magento connect it shows me this error.

```
 Unable to save version. Filename is not valid. Expected filename without ext is 3c3d7d19d8a80d1f0ed64e1d2db55836-1.0.0.
```

[image]

I have used same extension secure key name as my extension name while packaging process from magento admin.

So my question is, why I am facing this error? is there anything that I have missed here?

Answer (score 0):

I recently uploaded a extension to Magento connect for approval and got approved after long process. You should fulfill certain basic requirements as part of extension standards while uploading your extension to Magento connect for approval.

1. Your extension name should be like this

> vendor_extensionname-version.zip

It is advised to use only alphabets for vendor name and extension name. Also make sure they are in lowercase.

2. Make sure your extension contains valid composer.json file with required nodes in it or else your extension will no be accepted.

Comment: Thanks @Elan, but if an extension do a normal feature like ajaxcart feature then to it requires composer.json? I did package of my extension from magento's default feature so my extension created with the extension "Home_Ajaxcart-1.0.0". for magento 1.9

Comment: @darshan.dodiya I am not very sure about it. Please try uploading the extension if it requires composer.json file it will ask for it.